# Using metamask, I have seed phrase but unable to recover my old account

Tags: metamask, myetherwallet

I have been using metamask and for some reason there is a problem and my app stopped working so it gave me the only option to reinstall it, so i did it. I have my seed phrase but i didnot have my private key for the wallets. As I installed the application again and restored it with seed phrase my account address is completely change and i am unable to recover it. I just lost access to my funds and coins. Kindly suggest me how to deal with this problem? I am sure that i put the exact seed phrase but i didnot have private key. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

> I have my seed phrase but i didnot have my private key for the wallets

The seed phrase is the (master) private key.

If you have the seed phrase you can derive all child private keys, and therefore addresses. If the seed phrase is incorrect then you won't have access to your accounts.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I put my seed phrase correctly for sure, but when i logged in again my wallet address is completely changed, plus there is no funds in my eth wallet and its not even showing my binance smart chain wallet.

Comment: Have you re-added the Binance network? (Metamask doesn't support Binance by default, so you have to add it manually -> https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/connecting-metamask-to-binance-smart-chain)

Comment: I didn’t added binance yet, as i am not sure what to do, but i had some money in eth as well which is not reflecting in my account and my wallet address for eth is changed aswell.

Comment: Was it in Account 1 (in Metamask)? You can re-add accounts by clicking the "Create Account" button. Or are you sure you've selected the correct network?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I re-add account and it shows up my funds again. Thanks very much again. You saved me

Comment: Perfect - glad it worked :-)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you, but I do not understand the reason behind this issue. Why can an "Account 1" be different from an older Metamask and from a newer one? In theory if we make infinite many accounts, it should work, since they are derived from the same mnemonic seed phrases, but I think how it is derived changed over time in Metamask. Would love to hear other opinions too